# Making grid with certain spacing between lines along X and Y axis using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, vector-grid

We are doing the research about applying remote sensed data on hydro logical model . After delineating, the river basin from DEM data using Argis9.3, We have to map the remote sensed data derived from products like PERSIANN. Our task now is to create the grid with the same resolution with the available remote sensed data( for example 0.25degree x 0.25 degree). and have a certain corner that matches with the obtained data.

Does anyone know how to deal with our problem?

Comment: If I read your question right, in arcgis 10 you can output the footprints of your remote data as a grid. look at the raster mosaic.   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000003v000000

Comment: thx very much...but the problem is that we want to make regular polylines by longtitude and latitudes, e.g. 1 degree resolution. I know we can visualize the log. and lat. in layout view, but i want to draw polyline to divide my data into multiple cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool which does this is [Create Fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) - it can be used to create polygons, polylines and labels at regular intervals i.e. a grid of squares or rectangles in any coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcToolBox go to Data Management Tools

Choose Feature class -> create Fishnet, to make grid layer.

this clip will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loMEb5sv4tQ